# WhenEvent - energy conservation not valid

Tags: differential-equations, physics, event-detection, discontinuity

I would like to simulate the following conservative system, with purely elastic impacts (coefficient of restitution is 1). Applying the WhenEvents the energy of the system is not conserved.
How can I correct this?
[image]

```
T = 10;
a = 0.1;
b = 0.1;
c = 1
{solu[t_], {data}} =
  Reap[NDSolveValue[{a*u1''[t] + b*(u1[t] - u2[t]) == 0, 
     u2''[t] + u2[t] + b*(u2[t] - u1[t]) == 0, u1[0] == 0, 
     u1'[0] == 3, u2[0] == 0, u2'[0] == 0,
     WhenEvent[Abs[(u2[t] - u1[t])] == c, Sow[{t, u2[t] - u1[t]}]],
     WhenEvent[
      Abs[(u2[t] - u1[t])] == 
       c, {u1'[t] -> ((a - 1)*u1'[t] + 2*u2'[t])/(1 + a), 
       u2'[t] -> (2*a*u1'[t] + (1 - a)*u2'[t])/(1 + a)} ]},
    {u1[t], u2[t], t}, {t, 0, T}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001]];

Plot[a*(solu'[t][[1]])^2 + (solu'[t][[2]])^2 + 
  b*((solu[t][[1]]) - (solu[t][[2]]))^2 + (solu[t][[2]])^2, {t, 0, T},
  PlotRange -> {{0, T}, All}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "Energy"}]
```

[image: The energy decrease after the impacts]

Comment: This has been mentioned in the **Possible Issues** of document of `WhenEvent`: "With sequential event actions, the variables are modified in turn, …, To swap the variable values, use simultaneous events." So the correct way to set the event is: `WhenEvent[Abs[u2[t] - u1[t]] == 
  c, {u1'[t], u2'[t]} -> {((a - 1) u1'[t] + 2 u2'[t])/(1 + a), (
   2 a u1'[t] + (1 - a) u2'[t])/(1 + a)}]`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, we need to show the corrected code and the result

```
T = 10;
a = 1/10;
b = 1/10;
c = 1;
{U1, U2, U11, U21} = 
  NDSolveValue[{a*u1''[t] + b*(u1[t] - u2[t]) == 0, 
    u2''[t] + u2[t] + b*(u2[t] - u1[t]) == 0, u1[0] == 0, u1'[0] == 3,
     u2[0] == 0, u2'[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[
     Abs[u2[t] - u1[t]] == 
      c, {u1'[t], 
       u2'[t]} -> {((a - 1) u1'[t] + 2 u2'[t])/(1 + 
          a), (2 a u1'[t] + (1 - a) u2'[t])/(1 + a)}]}, {u1, u2, u1', 
    u2'}, {t, 0, T}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
energy[t_] := 
 a*(U11[t])^2 + (U21[t])^2 + b*((U1[t]) - (U2[t]))^2 + (U2[t])^2
Plot[energy[t] - energy[0], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> {{0, T}, All}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t", "Energy"}]
```

Here, the deviation of energy from the initial value of about $10^{-11}$
[image: fig1]

On the second fig. the solution is shown

```
Plot[{U1[t], U2[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: fig2]